# Adding elements into an RSS feed from another website?

Tags: php, xml, rss

So I'm currently getting this RSS feed http://www.footballwebpages.co.uk/league.xml?comp=1 , but the root element is unsupported so I need to add an `<rss>` tag to the bottom/top of the XML files. How would I go around doing that ? I've already managed to print it out here...

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: application/xhtml+xml");  
    $html = file_get_contents('http://www.footballwebpages.co.uk/league.xml?comp=1');
        echo $html;
?>
```

It gives me everything correctly apart from the `<rss>` tags at the bottom and top.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is the best way but explode the $html with `<leagueTable>`?

```
header("Content-type: application/xhtml+xml");  
$html = explode("<leagueTable>", file_get_contents('http://www.footballwebpages.co.uk/league.xml?comp=1'));
$html = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<rss>
<leagueTable>{$html[1]}
</rss>";
echo $html;
```

Comment: No luck at all with this code  "<?php
header("Content-type: application/xhtml+xml");
$html = explode("<leagueTable>", file_get_contents('http://www.footballwebpages.co.uk/league.xml?comp=1'));
$html = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rss>
<leagueTable>{$html[1]}
</rss>';?>"  It prints out a blank page

Comment: Try it now, I added the echo and removed the double quotes in the <?xml line.

Comment: Now receiving this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home1/gretar/public_html/table/index.php on line 3

Comment: It is something on your end, that script works fine when copied into a php file on my web server.  I assumed you had some knowledge of PHP.